# Collapsible <div> onclick of link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have something like the below:

```
$grabarticles = $db->prepare("
    SELECT title, message
        FROM articles
");
$grabarticles->execute();
foreach($grabarticles as $articles) {
    echo $articles["title"];
    //when a user clicks the text above, reveal the below
    echo "<div id='article'><br/><br/>";
    echo "&nbsp;".$articles["message"];
    echo "</div><br/><br/>";
    //when a user clicks the $articles["title"] again, it then collapses
}
```

I'm not too well versed in Javascript to know, but is there some kind of thing I can do to make the `$articles["title"]` clickable, and `onclick` expand below to display the contents of `$articles["message"]`, but also be reversible with another `onclick`? Here's an image to illustrate:

[image: desiredoutput]

I want each `<div>` to be separate from another, so if I open #1 by clicking `$article["title"] //1`, and then open #2 by clicking the appropriate text, I can then close #1 by reclicking it without interfering with #2.

Comment: add an event listener to each title and toggle an `.active` class... Looks like you are looking for a basic accordion effect.

Comment: If you did want an accordion effect, http://jsfiddle.net/K7XTq/1/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that's actually pretty nifty. I'm not too well versed in Javascript (in fact, I only really use it for `alert()`s), so this is pretty snazzy for someone generally new to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the article title in a DOM element that can have events bound to it, such as a span. Then give it a class so we can easily target it.

```
echo '<span class="article-title">', $articles["title"] ,'</span>';
```

Next, your `id` in your `foreach` loop should be a class, as you're generating multiple elements and only one element can have a single ID.

```
echo "<div class='article' style='display:none;'><br/><br/>"; // <--note the "class" instead of "id"
```

Now just make a click function to toggle the visibility of the element.

```
$('.article-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle(); // find the next element after this one and toggle its visibility
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this [collapsible DIV jQuery plugin](https://github.com/juven14/Collapsible) written by John Snyder.  It does exactly what you are looking for.

I use this on my blog you can see an example of it [here](http://cosmonautdreams.com/python/blog/jquery/embed/2013/10/09/Embded-Content-and-jQuery.html) and [here](http://cosmonautdreams.com/music/)

Sample HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <link href="/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.collapsible.js"></script>
    <div class='collapsible'>
       Header Text 1<span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
       <div class='content'>
          <div>
             Body Text 1
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class='collapsible'>
       Header Text 2<span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
       <div class='content'>
          <div>
             Body Text 2
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS to go along with it

```
/* START SECTION FOR COLLAPSEIBLE DIV */
.collapse-open {
/*    background:#000;
    color: #fff;*/
}

.collapse-open span {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background:url(/images/minus.png) center center no-repeat;
}

.collapse-close span {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:url(/images/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#testTitle').click(function (e) {
        if ($("#testcontent").is(":visible")) {
            $("#testcontent").slideUp("slow");
        }
        else {
            $("#testcontent").slideDown("slow");
        }
    });

});
```